# What is the meaning of 去想？Does it have to do with movement?

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, I don't understand the meaning of 去想： 但是学生们看到快餐就会买。他们只知道快餐好吃，不去想这些食品是不健康的。

I have never seen it before (去想). Is it that when the students go to the cafeteria, they don't think? Or does the verb 去 have nothing to do with moving

Comment: You can think of the expression as "will not proceed to think of..." 

What we say in English is more like "...快餐好吃，而不會想到這些..."

Comment: 去想 simply mean 'to think about'

Answer (score 3):

It's a colloquial using.

"去想" is meaning "do thinking" or "think about"

但是学生们看到快餐就会买。他们只知道快餐好吃，不去想这些食品是不健康的。

Students will buy the fast food when they saw it, they only knows the fast food is good to eat, but they never thinking about that fast food is unhealthy.

It's not a really moving but a thinking move in brain. Similar => Do the "think".